# Is there a way I can make jslint work with curly braces on the next line of my javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint

I changed my coding style from

```
function getParams(entity) {
    "use strict";
    var accountID = store.getItem('AccountID'),

    switch (entity) {
        case "Topic":
```

to

```
function getParams(entity) 
{

    "use strict";
    var accountID = store.getItem('AccountID'),

    switch (entity)
    {
        case "Topic":
```

Now I get any jslint errors such as:

Warning 6   JS Lint: Expected exactly one space between ')' and '{'.
Warning 9   JS Lint: Expected 'var' at column 9, not column 5.

I checked through the options but cannot find any option to unselect relating to line position. Also if there is one then could I add it to the top of my file?

Comment: Not really the right place to post this question. SO relates to programming/development, not how to change preferences of software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JavaScript is recommended to put opening braces on the same line for this reason:

```
function foo()
{
  return
  {
    a: 'foo'
  }
}

foo().a // error
```

This is more an advice than a solution but impossible to explain in a comment without new lines.

Comment: What causes this?  I see the error, not sure I follow why it's there.

Comment: Automatic semi-colon insertion treats a newline after certain keywords as a statement terminator. `return` is one of these keywords. So `return<new line here>27` is the same as `return;27;` instead of the more intuitive `return 27;`. This is a special case of ASI. In most other cases, ASI will continue a statement whenever possible, which causes even more weirdness, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, jSLint uses string javascript coding rules to check your javascript..

```
var store = {};
function getParams(entity) {
    "use strict";
    var accountID = store.getItem('AccountID');

    switch (entity) {
    case "Topic": 
        accountID = '0';
        break;
    }
}
```

For a function it expects just 1 space between the `)` and `{` characters .. It is not an issue but it is a coding rule..